# ngFor is not working angular 2 and display blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular, ngfor

I watched youtube video and I tried to do as exactly like the video on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKWDKmHvF78&index=8&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBYxWxJtLi8c6PGjNKGYGZZ but the ngFor doesn't work for me at all.
when I write with ngFor it display blank page.

//app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Config} from './config.service';
import {Video} from './Video';
import {PlaylistComponent} from './playlist.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/app.component.html',
    directives:[PlaylistComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    name="check";
    videos:Array<Video>;
    constructor(){
        this.videos=[
            new Video(1,"row1","check1","this is our first row"),
            new Video(1,"row2","check2","this is our second row"),
        ]
    }
}
```

//app.component.html

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<playlist [videos]="videos"></playlist>
```

//main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

//playlist.component.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  *ngFor="let v of videos">
            <td>{{v.id}}</td>
            <td>{{v.title}}</td>
            <td>{{v.desc}}</td>

        </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

//playlist.component.ts

```
/**
 * Created by Adir on 9/7/2016.
 */
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Video} from './Video';

@Component({
    selector:'playlist',
    templateUrl:'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
    inputs:['videos']
})

export class PlaylistComponent{
    onSelect(vid:Video){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vid));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a property with @Input() decorator to be able to pass videos as a parameter.

Comment: I have this '/**
 * Created by Adir on 9/7/2016.
 */
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Video} from './Video';

@Component({
    selector:'playlist',
    templateUrl:'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
    inputs:['videos']
})

export class PlaylistComponent{
    onSelect(vid:Video){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vid));
    }
} '

Comment: You don't need inputs:[video]. Instead declare @Input() video; in playlist.component.

Comment: how to write it?     @Input(videos);
??

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inputs from Component Definition and add input property inside the class.

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
export class PlaylistComponent{
    @Input() public videos: Array<Video>;
    onSelect(vid:Video){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vid));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly like this video , there it works as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKWDKmHvF78&index=8&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBYxWxJtLi8c6PGjNKGYGZZ

Comment: the same I also get exceptio EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let v of video">
            <td>{{v.id}}</td>
            <td>{{v.title}}</td>
"): PlaylistComponent@9:13